# Show All Files by default

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to switch on Visual Studio's Solution Explorer 'Show All Files' setting by default?

Comment: i don't think so, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

Not a Visual Studio setting, but helps if you use version control.

Insert following lines in ".vcxproj" or solution wide ".props" file.

```html
<PropertyGroup Label = "MySettings">
    <ShowAllFiles>true</ShowAllFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```