# Show all files by default for VB.Net in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, project-template

I would like to know, in **Visual Studio 2013**, how to modify the default VB **WindowsForms** template to always show all the files (the referenced assemblies).

For **VS2010** exists a question and a solution here: [Show All Files by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272917/show-all-files-by-default)

However, I've reproduced the steps of that trick, but it doesn't work for **Visual Studio 2013**.

The older trick consists in add the `windowsapplication.vbproj.user` (with the `ShowAllFiles` attribute set) in the template folder, and then, adding this entry into the `windowsapplication.vstemplate` file:

```
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project File="WindowsApplication.vbproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      ...
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true"  TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$.vbproj.user">windowsapplication.vbproj.user</ProjectItem>
      ...
    </Project>
  </TemplateContent>
```

However, when creating a new project, the `windowsapplication.vbproj.user` is not copied to the desired destination.

By my own I noticed that seems an additional entry is required in the `windowsapplication.vbproj` file to tell the IDE that should not ignore/miss the `windowsapplication.vbproj.user` file, so, just I tried to see what happens adding this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    ...
    <None Include="$safeprojectname$.vbproj.user">
      <Generator>MyApplicationCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>windowsapplication.vbproj.user</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
```

With this new modification now the file is copied, however, is not properly copied, seems that the file is just included in the solution explorer as part of the project, and nothing more, because I still need to press the **Show All Files** button to show the "hidden" references. But ...at least doing this, if I close and reopen the project, like the file was copied, the changes take effect at this point, but of course is a weird behavior the need to close/open the project once to see the **Show All Files** button properly pressed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this hack doesn't work anymore.  It documents the wrong directory, it should be ProjectTemplatesCache, but that doesn't otherwise fix anything.  The file *does* get copied but then it immediately gets overwritten, the VB project system now always creates a projectname.vbproj.user file for a new project.  An empty one.  Used to work in older versions because it did not yet do that, creating the .user file only when needed.

This otherwise has a very easy fix, you just need to wait another 3 weeks.  VS2015 always shows the References node for VB.NET project.  A design change that was inspired by the added support for Live Code Analyzers, a Roslyn feature.  The References node shows which analyzers are enabled for a project.

Use Project > Properties > References until you update.

Comment: Thanks. Good thing to know that they will finally implement that change ... because VB.Net to be considered as the darling language and the jewel of Microsoft, unlike C#, they have taken too long to facilitate this task. I do not understand these aesthetic changes of Microsoft, firstlly they decide to disables the node visibility permanentlly by default, now  in VS2015 they decided to activate forever the node visibility by default, anything but add an option for the end user to decide whether to display or not the References node by default, anything but that, what an stupid thing.